# Replace all values of a column in a dataframe with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to replace all the values of a column in a spark dataframe with a particular value. I am using pyspark. I tried something like -

`new_df = df.withColumn('column_name',10)`

Here I want to replace all the values in the column `column_name` to `10`. In pandas this could be done by 
`df['column_name']=10`. I am unable to figure out how to do the same in Spark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be easier to use `lit` as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
new_df = df.withColumn('column_name', lit(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) to replace the value. However you can use currying to bring support to different values.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

def replacerUDF(value):
    return udf(lambda x: value)

new_df = df.withColumnRenamed("newCol", replacerUDF(10)(col("column_name")))
```